# PHP - echo the opening and closing of tags from array

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, html-parsing

Here I have an array and there is content situated inside it, their is either, one object, two, or more - depending on the tags required; the first element nested in the multidimensional array would be the textual output, unless it is an array, then the first element inside the array would be the text.

However, the other content in the array is in reference to the HTML tag they correspond to, such as:

```
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => bo          <====== Text to output
        [1] => bold        <====== tag to be within
    )
```

However, in the module of simplicity, I would prefer for the content not to constantly repeat such responses, like:

```
This is a test <b>bo</b><i><b>ld</b></i><i>,</i> <u><i>u</i></u><u>nderline</u> ...
```

Instead the output should be:

```
This is a test<b>bo<i>ld</i></b><i>, <u>u</u></i><u>nderline</u> ...
```

This is the PHP code I have for it so far...

```
$use = array();
$base = "";
foreach ($build as $part => $data) {
//  print_r($use);
    if(!is_array($data)){
        $base .= $data;
    } else {
        $text = array_shift($data);
        if(!is_array($data[0])){
            $data = array($data[0]);
        } else {
            $data = $data[0];
        }
        $removed = array_diff($use,$data);

        foreach (($data) as $tag) {
            if (in_array($tag, array_diff($use,$data))) {
                $base .= "<\/" . $tag . ">";
            } elseif(!in_array($tag, $use)){
                $base .= "<" . $tag . ">";
                array_push($use, $tag);
            }
        }
        $use = $data;
        $base .= $text; 
    }
}
print_r($base);
```

And here is the array if required (in JSON format!):

```
["This is a test\nIncluding ",["bo","bold"],["ld",["italic","bold"]],[", ","italic"],["u",["underline","italic"]],["nderlined","underline"],", ",["strike-through","strike"],", and ",["italic","italic"],"\ntext:\n\n",["numbered lists",["underline","strike","italic","bold"]],["\n",[]],"as well as",["\n",[]],["non ordered lists","http:\/\/test.com"],["\n",[]],"it works very well",["\n",[]],["try it","http:\/\/google.com"],"\n",["http:\/\/google.com",["bold","http:\/\/google.com"]],"\n\n",["wow","bold"],"\n",["lol","bold"]]
```

Any help would be much appreciated... thanks!

Comment: You can do this with JavaScript using `document.createElement()` and I'm sure it would be a lot easier... does it really have to be done with PHP?

Comment: @Zeke sadly it does have to be done in PHP to make everything display the content as fast as possibly, if you have any idea's on how to do this in PHP , that'll be much appreciated - as i've been trying to work around this for 8 hours...

Comment: Okay, I'm asking because you provided the array in JSON format, which suggests that JavaScript is the way to go... but sure. The PHP script takes the array in JSON format? I mean, it has to be decoded first, am I right? (This one being your `$build` variable, I suppose)

Comment: @zeke that is correct (I put it in JSON format, at I thought it would be easier for people to load JSON into PHP for testing purposes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm honestly not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for. It would be great to have a full desired output... but I believe this is as close as it gets. It took me 3 hours so it better be it. It's a great question, very hard to accomplish.

> I did `print_r(htmlentities($base))`, but you can simply do `print_r($base)` to see the formatted result. I did that because it was easier to check with the output you provided in the question.
>
> Also, I modified your JSON because some tags specified there are non-existent. For example, I changed `underline` for `u`, `italic` for `i`, `bold` for `b`. Alternatives are `em`, `strong`... anyway, that's just a side-note.

```
<?php
$build = json_decode('["This is a test\nIncluding ",["bo","b"],["ld",["i","b"]],[", ","i"],["u",["u","i"]],["nderlined","u"],", ",["strike-through","strike"],", and ",["italic","i"],"\ntext:\n\n",["numbered lists",["u","strike","i","b"]],["\n",[]],"as well as",["\n",[]],["non ordered lists","http:\/\/test.com"],["\n",[]],"it works very well",["\n",[]],["try it","http:\/\/google.com"],"\n",["http:\/\/google.com",["b","http:\/\/google.com"]],"\n\n",["wow","b"],"\n",["lol","b"]]', true);
$used = [];
$base = '';
foreach($build as $data){
    if(is_array($data)){
        $text = array_shift($data);
        $tags = $data[0];
        if(!is_array($data[0])){
            $tags = [$data[0]];
        }
        $elements = '';
        $tagsToClose = array_diff($used, $tags);
        $changes = true;
        $i = 0;
        foreach($tagsToClose as $tag){
            while($changes){
                $changes = false;
                if($lastOpened != $tag){
                    $changes = true;
                    $elements .= '</'.$lastOpened.'>';
                    unset($used[$i++]);
                    $lastOpened = $used[$i];
                }
            }
            $elements .= '</'.$tag.'>';
            $key = array_search($tag, $used);
            unset($used[$key]);
        }
        foreach($tags as $tag){
            if(!in_array($tag, $used)){
                $elements .= '<'.$tag.'>';
                array_unshift($used, $tag);
                $lastOpened = $tag;
            }
        }
        $elements .= $text;
        $data = $elements;
    }
    $base .= $data;
}
unset($used);
$base .= '</'.$lastOpened.'>';
print_r(htmlentities($base));
?>
```

#### EDIT

And here's the result I got, just in case you run into some trouble testing or to check with your results or whatever:

> `This is a test Including <b>bo<i>ld</i></b><i>, <u>u</u></i><u>nderlined, </u><strike>strike-through, and </strike><i>italic text: <u><strike><b>numbered lists</b></strike></u></i> as well as <http://test.com>non ordered lists</http://test.com> it works very well <http://google.com>try it <b>http://google.com </b></http://google.com><b>wow lol</b>`

Comment: Did you ever check my answer? It took me a lot of time to do it and you never said another word for 6 days. Now you have an answer out of the blue? What was the point in asking the question if you weren’t going to see the answers?

Comment: Well, you could have just commented here that you got around the problem while saying something about my answer, even if it was negative, especially because I was not sure if I even helped a little. I'm not mad, but it felt like you ignored my answer entirely.

Comment: well I'm sorry if I offended you

Comment: No, not at all, everything's fine. But seriously, don't just add an answer 7 days after another answer was posted and not say anything on the first answer. It's just rude (because _you_ asked the question, obviously).

Comment: Well, im sorry, I thought that I did validate it as the right answer...

Comment: It's alright, no hard feelings. I don't mind about the answer being validated or not, that's another matter. I mean, it's fine that you found your answer... what made it bad is that it had been 7 days. Then again, no hard feelings, for reals.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours, this was my solution that I ended up with:

```
$build = json_decode('["This is a test Including\u00a0",["bo","bold"],["ld",["italic","bold"]],[",\u00a0","italic"],["u",["underline","italic"]],["nderlined,\u00a0","underline"],"strike-through, and\u00a0",["italic text:\u00a0","italic"],"it works very well\u00a0try it\u00a0",["http:\/\/google.com",["bold","http:\/\/google.com"]],["\u00a0wow lol","bold"]]',true);
$standard = array("bold"=>"b","underline"=>"u","strike"=>"s","italic"=>"i","link"=>"a","size"=>null);
$lists = array("ordered"=>"ol","bullet"=>"ul");
$size = array("huge"=>"2.5em","large"=>"1.5em");

$base = "";
foreach($build as $part){
    $use = array();
    $tags = true;
    $len = 1;
    if(!is_array($part) or count($part) == 1){
        $text = $part;
        $tags = false;
        $part = array();
    } else {
        $text = array_shift($part);

        if(count($part) == 1){
            if(is_array($part[0])){
                $part = $part[0];
            }
        }
        if(!is_array($part)){
            $part = array($part);
        }
    }
    if($tags){
        foreach ($part as $tag) {
            if(!in_array($tag, array_keys($standard)) && !in_array($tag, array_keys($lists)) && !in_array($tag, array_keys($size))){
                $base .= '<a href="' . $tag . '" title="' . $tag . '" class="link">';
                $tag = "link";
            } elseif(in_array($tag, array_keys($size))){
                $base .= "<span style='font-size:" . $size[$tag] . "'>";
            } elseif(!in_array($tag, array_keys($lists))) {
                $base .= "<" . $standard[$tag] . ">";
            }
            array_push($use, $tag);
        }
        $base .= $text;
        foreach (array_reverse($part) as $tag) {
            if(!in_array($tag, array_keys($standard)) && !in_array($tag, array_keys($lists)) && !in_array($tag, array_keys($size))){
                $base .= '</a>';
            } elseif(in_array($tag, array_keys($size))){
                $base .= "</span>";
            } elseif (!in_array($tag, array_keys($lists))) {
                $base .= "</" . $standard[$tag] . ">";
            }
            array_push($use, $tag);
        }
    } else {
        $base .= $text;
    }
}
print_r($base);
```